# TextMate 2: How to permanently default to soft tabs (spaces instead of tabs)?

Tags: textmate

#### SETUP

OS X 10.8
TextMate 2 -r9283

#### QUESTION

How can I **permanently** force TextMate to to **always** default to **soft tabs** (use spaces, not tabs)?

I want to know how to make TextMate **default** to this setting so that I don't have to constantly convert tabs to spaces while working on a file.

How do you **permanently** tell TextMate 2 to prefer soft tabs?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

TextMate 2 uses a special file called `.tm_properties` to control lots of settings in the app. It will use `~/.tm_properties` if present for global defaults. You can also add one inside a source tree to control settings for a particular project.

The setting you're looking for is:

```
softTabs = true
```

Just add that line to `~/.tm_properties` (or create it if it doesn't exist).

You can read more about this file [here](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/git-style-configuration/).

Answer (score 16):

Put the following in `~/.tm_properties`:

```
softWrap = true
tabSize = 4
softTabs = true
```

Comment: `softWrap` is unrelated to this question.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic, ``soft`` is the relation...